# How to start YouTube Video by clicking on its cover image (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that works fine to show YouTube Video.

What I want is when I click on the cover image then it should start to play video.

How I can implement it?

Thank you!

```
<div id="video" style="display: none;">
            <object width="370" height="230">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/QN20iMIMxvk?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0">
                </param>
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/QN20iMIMxvk?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" width="370" height="230"></embed>
            </object>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('video').style.display = 'block'; javascript:document.getElementById('videopic').style.display = 'none'; void(0);">
            <img id="videopic" src="@Url.Content("~/images/coverimage1.jpg")"  style="width:370px; height:230px;" alt="Media" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Implement http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/
2. Add 2 JS functions

   function playvideo() 
   { 
                   document.getElementById('video').style.display = 'block';
                   document.getElementById('videopic').style.display = 'none'; 
   }

   function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
           var ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
           if (ytplayer) {
               ytplayer.playVideo();
           }
   }
3. And use the code to show youtube video & the cover image

   < div id="video" style="display: none;">
                       
                           You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.

   ```
                       var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
                       var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
                       swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/QN67iMIMxvk?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                              "ytapiplayer", "370", "230", "8", null, null, params, atts);

                   </script>
               </div>
               <img id="videopic"  src="@Url.Content("~/images/coverimage1.jpg")" onclick="playvideo();"  style=" cursor:pointer; width:370px; height:230px;" alt="" />
   ```